# How to turn a require __FILE__ + 'file.rb' into require 'file'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this at the top of the file:

**parser_spec.rb:**

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/parser.rb'
```

Which has a class inside:

**parser.rb:**

```
class Scraper
  def scrape_department(file)
```

Both files are in the `rails/project` folder.

How to do it so that I can include that file by just doing `require 'parser'`?

Comment: If you are using Rails and this file is in the lib directory, you might simply load all your libs file using `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` in `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Just means to look for the file in the directory of the caller.

Try using

```
require_relative 'parser'
```

By the way, I would suggest renaming your file scraper.rb since this is the name of your class inside that file.

Comment: Yes, I renamed it scraper.rb. But I followed your suggestion and I got `/home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- scraper (LoadError)
 from /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubyg`. Both files are in the rails/project folder.

Comment: According to the documentation here http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative, the file path cannot be determined

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [`require_relative`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative):

```
require_relative 'parser.rb'
```

From the docs:

> Ruby tries to load the library ... relative to the requiring file’s path.